# Binding of NSArrayController programatically to receive selected object

Tags: swift, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

this is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var dataArrayController: NSArrayController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataArrayController.addObserver(self,
                                    forKeyPath: "selection.name",
                                    options: .new, context: &myContext)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if (context == &myContext) {
        if (keyPath == "selection.name")
        {

            if let newValue = change?[.newKey] {
                print("Selection changed: \(newValue)")
            }
        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to catch selected object's name similar to NSTextField (which I do in IB and is really easy). However here I get in console:

```
Selection changed: <null>
```

So I'm receiving the message but don't get the object. What's wrong?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Semantics, perhaps, but... KVO isn't "binding" - if you were binding programmatically I would expect to see `bind` in your code.

Comment: Ok, I added:  self.bind("value", to: dataArrayController, withKeyPath: "selection.name", options: nil). How can I respond to change of "selection.name"?

Comment: With that binding, when `selection.name` changes, `value` changes.  And visa versa.  If you want to react to the selection changing, the easy way is usually implementing the delegate protocol for the view.  You could certainly use KVO on `selection.name` as well... KVO's just tetchy sometimes.  It's common to have a binding in IB *and* an implementation of something like `tableViewSelectionDidChange`.